# Problema al crear URLS amigables con htaccess y expresiones regulares

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Saludos, estoy creando una pagina web dinámica en la cual se carga cierta información mediante una variable `$_GET`.  y las `url` me quedan del tipo

```
      https://www.dominio.com/deals/deals.php?deal_id=483
```

donde la variable `deal_id` es la ID de mi producto y con esto muestro la info en la pagina haciendo una consulta `mysql`, como el nombre,precio,etc y todo bien en esta parte.
La cosa es que leí que utilizando el archivo `htaccess` puedo cambiar la `url` para hacerla mas amigable a los buscadores por un tema de SEO y colocarla de tipo :

```
     https://www.dominio.com/deals/nombre-articulo
```

la cuestión es que he intentado varias expresiones regulares y no logro los resultados deseados ya que la `url` no muestra cambios y se sigue mostrando igual aun después de incluir la expresión regular en el `htaccess` y seguramente es porque no se implementar los cambios, me podrían ayudar? , he utilizado esta expresión

```
    RewriteRule ^deals/(\w+)$ deals.php?deal_id=$1
```

pero realmente no se como implementarla, y sobre todo si puedo incluir el nombre del producto en la `URL` **ademas de la ID del producto**, algo asi como concatenar el nombre del producto a la `URL`.

He pensado en pasar via get el parametro del nombre del producto aunque no lo use tipo:

```
   https://www.dominio.com/deals/deals.php?deal_id=483&nombre=nombre-producto/
```

pero ahora como seria la expresion regular para enmascarar esta `URL` ?

Comment: Okey, tu mismo te has respondido tu pregunta, lógico, tienes que pasar el ID, ya que la URL ficticia solo es una mascara, pero la URL real a la cual se hace la petición, así que sino pasas el id, obvio no funcionara .

Comment: `RewriteRule ^deals/([0-9]+)$ deals.php?deal_id=$1` ... numerico por que debes pasar el ID, si tu quieres pasar otro parametro aparte no hay problema, pero el ID debe estar presenta si es el valor con el cual haras la consulta, no ?

Comment: claro, eso lo comprendo, pero no existe la manera de concatenar a la url el nombre del producto ?, la id se vería porque la necesito pasar via $_get , pero me gustaria que se viera el nombre del producto en la url , como logro eso ?

Comment: pues es sencillo, cuando tu llamas a esta url `deals.php?deal_id=$1` es por que estas dando click sobre un enlace desde el cual tus has cargado los ID a un cierto numeros de links que podrian representar las entradas de un blog, por ejemplo, entonces, si tu en tu pagina principal, cargas todas ellas y haces un link como `deals.php?deal_id=$1&titulo=HOLA_MUNDO` podrias rescribir la URL como `RewriteRule ^deals/([0-9]+)/(\w+)$ deals.php?deal_id=$1&titulo=$2` no es para nada complicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal: `\w` es una secuencia de escape para `[0-9_a-zA-Z]`.
El guión (`-`) no está incluido en `\w`.

Podrías:

- incluirlo usando `[-\w]+`
- o algo más genérico, cualquier caracter excepto una barra: `[^/]+`

---

Ahora bien, no definiste el formato en el que querés pasar el ID en la URL. Puede ser:

1. Formato: `https://www.dominio.com/deals/id/nombre-articulo`

   ```python
   RewriteRule ^deals/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ deals.php?deal_id=$1&nombre=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
   ```

2. Formato: `https://www.dominio.com/deals/nombre-articulo-id`

   ```python
   RewriteRule ^deals/([^/]+)-(\d+)/?$ deals.php?deal_id=$2&nombre=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
   ```

3. O directamente no pasar el id.
   Formato: `https://www.dominio.com/deals/nombre-articulo`

   Pero eso implica que en tu script, cuando no recibas ningún valor en `$_GET['deal_id']`, vas a tener que buscar en la base de datos el id que corresponde al nombre que recibiste en `$_GET['nombre']`. En cuyo caso, deberías tener cuidado y pensar bien la implementación porque quizás 2 productos tienen el mismo nombre, o el nombre de un producto puede cambiar (dependerá de tus reglas de negocio).

   ```python
   RewriteRule ^deals/([^/]+)/?$ deals.php?nombre=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta configuración en el .htaccess a mi me funciona de maravilla.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^p/(\w+)/?$ deals.php?deal_id=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^p/(\w+)/(\w+)$ deals.php?deal_id=$1&deal_nombre=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^p/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ deals.php?deal_id=$1&deal_nombre=$2&otro_parametro=$3 [L]
```

En esta página usan lo que mencionas, http://www.perudataconsult.net/p/blog/apple-lanza-su-nuevo-dispositivo-movil

Lo mas seguro es que tengan un campo en la base de datos llamado link_post, donde se guarda el titulo del Artículo en un formato que no contenga espacios, tildes, eñes u otros caracteres extraños.